# How to hide this object

Tags: modifiers, vertices

Can you please help me? This green object is attached to another some 6 meters away. When I delete it The object it is linked to also disappears. What can I do so it will not appear in my scene, please?

Alan Yuri[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i think you are selecting the whole group for selecing that empty. currently that red area is activated. just press the green area to select just the empty and press x and delete and it should work fine!